# VB.NET Get Website IP Address Using HTTPWebRequest?

Tags: vb.net, class, httpwebrequest, ip, httpwebresponse

Is it possible to obtain the website's IP address that you are connecting to on a HTTPWebRequest session?

I'm looking to do this for an authentication check in a licensing class to prevent people from chainging their hosts.etc file and sending false replies to crack my software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[When retrieving URL via HttpWebRequest, can I see the IP address of the destination server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365586/when-retrieving-url-via-httpwebrequest-can-i-see-the-ip-address-of-the-destinat)

Check out the thread about this might help you

Cheers

Truez

Answer (score 0):

Above thread was correct, code used below:

```
For Each IP In Dns.GetHostEntry("website.com").AddressList
            If IP.ToString() <> "websiteip" Then
                MessageBox.Show("Not connecting to correct IP address")
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
```